# MissingSchemaError issue for dynamically inserted schema in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have inserted data using dynamically create schema model.But i am not able to get data from mongodb because below the error.

If i use nodemon run dev each execution except first i am getting this MissingSchemaError. How to resolve this issue.

> MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model
>   "Chocolates". Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
>       at Mongoose.model (D:\Projects\Angular\made\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:502:13)
>       at module.exports.getTableData (D:\Projects\Angular\made\server\controllers\products.controller.js:45:30)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Projects\Angular\made\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (D:\Projects\Angular\made\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (D:\Projects\Angular\made\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Projects\Angular\made\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at D:\Projects\Angular\made\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
>       at Function.process_params (D:\Projects\Angular\made\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
>       at next (D:\Projects\Angular\made\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
>       at Function.handle (D:\Projects\Angular\made\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
>       at router (D:\Projects\Angular\made\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Projects\Angular\made\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at trim_prefix (D:\Projects\Angular\made\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
>       at D:\Projects\Angular\made\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
>       at Function.process_params (D:\Projects\Angular\made\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
>       at next (D:\Projects\Angular\made\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)

newmodelschema.js:

```
 const db = mongoose.createConnection(
     "mongodb://localhost:27017/madeproduct_dbname", {
         useNewUrlParser: true,
         useUnifiedTopology: true
     }
 );

 function dynamicModel(suffix) {
     var collsName = suffix.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + suffix.slice(1);
     var collsSmall = suffix.toLowerCase();
     var newSchema = new Schema({
         p_id: {
             type: String
         },
         product_name: {
             type: String
         },
         product_img: {
             type: String
         } 
     }, {
         versionKey: false,
         collection: collsSmall
     });
     try {
         if (db.model(collsName)) return db.model(collsName);
     } catch (e) {
         if (e.name === 'MissingSchemaError') {
             return db.model(collsName, newSchema, collsSmall);
         }
     }
 }
```

db.js:

```
   module.exports = dynamicModel;
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, (err) => {
    if (!err) { console.log('MongoDB connection succeeded.'); } else { console.log('Error in MongoDB connection : ' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2)); }
}); 
require('./createschema.model');
```

product.controller.js:

```
module.exports.getTableData = (req, res, next) => {
    let collection = req.query.collection;
    let tabledata = mongoose.model(collection); //Getting MissingSchemaError Error 
    tabledata.find({}, function(err, docs) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('ss' + err);
            return;
        } else {
            console.log("Successful loaded");
            res.json({ data: docs, success: true, msg: 'Products data loaded.' });
        }
    })
}
//Create new model
module.exports.newCollection = (req, res, next) => {
    var collectionName = req.query.collectionName;
    var NewModel = require(path.resolve('./models/newmodelschema.model.js'))(collectionName);           
    NewModel.create({ }, function(err, doc) {});
}
```

config.js:

```
// check env.
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
// fetch env. config
var config = require('./config.json');
var envConfig = config[env];
// add env. config values to process.env
Object.keys(envConfig).forEach(key => process.env[key] = envConfig[key]);
```

config.json:

```
{
    "development": {
        "PORT": 3000,
        "MONGODB_URI": "mongodb://localhost:27017/madeproduct_dbname",
        "JWT_SECRET": "SECRET#123",
        "JWT_EXP": "10m"
    },
    "production": {
        "PORT": 80,
        "MONGODB_URI": "mongodb://xxxxx/DB_Name",
        "JWT_SECRET": "SECRET#123",
        "JWT_EXP": "2m"
    }
}
```

index.router.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router(); 
const ctrlProducts = require('../controllers/products.controller'); 
router.get('/getTableData', ctrlProducts.getTableData);  
module.exports = router;
```

app.js:

```
require('./config/config');
require('./models/db'); 
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const passport = require('passport');
const rtsIndex = require('./routes/index.router');
var app = express();

// middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use('/api', rtsIndex);

// error handler
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    if (err.name === 'ValidationError') {
        var valErrors = [];
        Object.keys(err.errors).forEach(key => valErrors.push(err.errors[key].message));
        res.status(422).send(valErrors)
    } else {
        console.log(err);
    }
});

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.json({ 'error': err.message })
});  
// start server
      app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => console.log(`Server started at port : ${process.env.PORT}`));
```

I am checking schema registered or not using below code. Schema is registred

```
const mongoURI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/madeproduct_dbname'
        // notice the mongoose.createConnection instead of mongoose.connect
    const conn = mongoose.createConnection(mongoURI);
    conn.on('open', function() {
        conn.db.listCollections().toArray(function(err, collectionNames) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            } 
            console.log(collectionNames);
            // conn.close();
        });
    });
```

console.log(collectionNames); result below

```
[
  {
    name: 'chocolates',
    type: 'collection',
    options: {},
    info: { readOnly: false, uuid: [Binary] },
    idIndex: { v: 2, key: [Object], name: '_id_', ns: 'madeproduct_dbname.chocolates' }
  }
]
```

Comment: Where are you calling calling `dynamicModel`. How are you determing the suffix. can you show that piece of code..

Comment: Please check in product.controller.js:

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: You're not showing where, during startup, all the models are actually being created from the collections that are present in your database. But to be honest, I wonder if Mongoose is the right tool for this sort of setup, it seems to be it's much easier to use "regular" MongoDB on the dynamically created collections. FWIW, I wouldn't recommend using unverified data (`req.query.collectionName`) to create/query your database, it's a recipe for misuse.

Comment: @robertklep:  So What i want to do? How to do  "regular" MongoDB on the dynamically created collections?

Comment: @robertklep: After created schema first time only it is working..if i refresh or reload the page using  node app.js it is not working

Comment: @PappaS you're creating collections, but I don't see where you create the schema's and models during startup. This is required for Mongoose to work correctly. To directly work with MongoDB, use [the MongoDB driver](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native).

Comment: @robertklep:Please check module.exports.newCollection = (req, res, next) => {....I am passing new collection name by this url to create new schema and model http://localhost:3000/api/newCollection?collectionName=Chocolates

Comment: @PappaS but I don't see `newCollection` getting called anywhere during startup.

Comment: @robertklep: I have one text box..After typed new collection name then i am passing the text by this url http:localhost:3000/api/newCollection?collectionName=textboxvalue

Comment: @robertklep: You know we can pass value by url in server side using nodejs like createCollectionintoDb(collname){
  return this.http.get(environment.apiBaseUrl + '/newCollection?collectionName='+collname);
}

Comment: @PappaS to be honest, you're much better off just using MongoDB directly, without Mongoose's schema and models.

Comment: @robertklep: 75% work completed using mongoose..So If i go with mongodb lot of rework i will do..

Comment: @PappaS you can mix MongoDB and Mongoose, so you can leave the 75% Mongoose code that is working (I presume) and use MongoDB for the "dynamic" parts.

Comment: @robertklep: How do it? Can you edit my code?

Comment: @PappaS if you have a specific problem I'm happy to help, but SO is not a site for people to post their non-working code for others to fix it. It's not very difficult to use the MongoDB driver.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get data from mongodb for dynamically created schema model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62170472/how-to-get-data-from-mongodb-for-dynamically-created-schema-model)

Comment: DO NOT CREATE DUPLICATE QUESTIONS FOR THE SAME PROBLEM!