# How to get data from mongodb for dynamically created schema model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to get data from mongodb but could not. Because below the error is the reason.I have inserted data into mongodb by dynamically creating schema model.So I am not able to get data from mongodb.How to get data from mongodb for (dynamically creating schema) collection? Please help anyone.I have searched in google but no use.

> MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Tea". 
>   Use mongoose.model(name, schema) at Mongoose.model

createschema.js

```
const db = mongoose.createConnection(
     "mongodb://localhost:27017/products", {
         useNewUrlParser: true,
         useUnifiedTopology: true
     }
 );

 function dynamicModel(suffix) {
     var collsName = suffix.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + suffix.slice(1);
     var collsSmall = suffix.toLowerCase();
     var newSchema = new Schema({
         pid: {
             type: String
         },
         product_name: {
             type: String
         },
         product_price: {
             type: Number
         } 
     }, {
         versionKey: false,
         collection: collsSmall
     });
     try {
         if (db.model(collsName)) return db.model(collsName);
     } catch (e) {
         if (e.name === 'MissingSchemaError') {
             return db.model(collsName, newSchema, collsSmall);
         }
     }
 }

 module.exports = dynamicModel;
```

data.controller.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
module.exports.getCollectionData = (req, res, next) => {
    let collection = req.query.collection;
    let tabledata = mongoose.model(collection); //Got MissingSchemaError  
    tabledata.find({}, function(err, docs) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        } else {
            res.json({ data: docs, success: true, msg: 'Products data loaded.' });
        }
    })
}

//Create model
module.exports.newCollection = (req, res, next) => {
    var collectionName = req.query.collectionName;
    var NewModel = require(path.resolve('./models/createschema.model.js'))(collectionName);           
    NewModel.create({ }, function(err, doc) {});
}
```

db.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, (err) => {
    if (!err) { console.log('MongoDB connection succeeded.'); } else { console.log('Error in MongoDB connection : ' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2)); }
}); 
require('./createschema.model');
```

api call:

```
     http://localhost:3000/api/getCollectionData?collection='Tea'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `db.model` instead of `mongoose.model` in function `getCollectionData`
Since you created the `collection` on that particular `connection`, you have to use the same `connection` to get the `model` as well.

```
const db = mongoose.createConnection(
 "mongodb://localhost:27017/products", {
     useNewUrlParser: true,
     useUnifiedTopology: true
 }
);

module.exports.getCollectionData = (req, res, next) => {
    let collection = req.query.collection;
    let tabledata = db.model(collection); //Change here  
    tabledata.find({}, function(err, docs) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        } else {
            res.json({ data: docs, success: true, msg: 'Products data loaded.' });
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Again i am getting same error: MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Tea".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema)

Comment: You have any other idea?

Comment: I have added my db.js..Can you check it?

Answer (score 0):

1. You fundamentally misuse `mongoose.model()` / `connection.model()`.

   This function can ONLY be used to CREATE a NEW mongoose model using
   required model name and schema deffinition parameters.
2. In `createschema.js` when you have `try {if (db.model(collsName))
   return db.model(collsName);} catch` you are NOT checking if model
   already exists. `db.model(collsName)` will always throw an error
   because you are not providing second required parameter with schema
   definition.

   I presume you are trying to check if model already exists and if so
   return it. Please see [documentation for
   Connection.prototype.models](https://devdocs.io/mongoose/api/connection#connection_Connection-models).  the fragment above should
   therefore be:

```
try {
   // db is an instance of mongoose.Connection    
   let existingModel = db.models[collsName];   
   if (existingModel) return existingModel; 
} catch
```

3. Likewise in `data.controller.js` `getCollectionData` currently you are
   calling a method to create a new mongoose model 'mongoose.model()',
   but don't provide a schema (hence why you get MissingSchemaError)

you need to EITHER

- get the model from mongoose instance (if already registered as you seem to imply)

```
let tabledata = mongoose.connection.models[collection];
```

OR

- create a new mongoose model

```
const dynamicModel = require('./createschema.js');
let tabledata =
dynamicModel(collection)
```

Comment: Getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined  in this line  NewModel.create({ }, function(err, doc) {});

Comment: I have changed your code like try { 
   let existingModel = db.models[collsName];   
   if (existingModel) {return existingModel;}else{return db.model(collsName, newSchema, collsSmall); } 
} catch       Then only it is working..I think this is correct method rite?